# Filter date array in f#

Tags: date, f#, filter

I have an array containing dates without weekends (not necessarily business days). Now I want only one date per month and only from a certain day. If the day does not exist in the array, the following existing day should be in the resulting list.

For example:
Given an array: 1.2.2010, 2.2.2010, 5.2.2010, 6.2.2010, ..., 1.3.2010, 2.3.2010, ..., 1.4.2010, 4.4.2010

I want all the dates on the 2nd on every month

Result: 2.2.2010, 2.3.2010, 4.4.2010

How do I do that in F#? Please provide an educating and nice solution, I try to learn F#. I know how to do it in an imperative way :)

Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

```
// Your input list with dates
let input = [DateTime.Now]
// We want 2nd day or later
let number = 2

input 
  // First, create group of dates for every Year/Month 
  // (so that all days in specifc month are in a single group)
  |> Seq.groupBy (fun dt -> dt.Year, dt.Month)
  |> Seq.map (fun ((y, m), dates) ->
     // We want only dates that are later (or equal to) this 'limit'
     let limit = new DateTime(y, m, number)
     // Remove dates before the limit and then select minimal date
     dates |> Seq.filter (fun d -> d >= limit) |> Seq.min)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another (assuming sorted input):

```
type DateTime = System.DateTime

let filterDayOrFollowing day (input:DateTime[]) =
    (input, ([], None))
    ||> Array.foldBack (fun date (acc, following:DateTime option) ->
        if date.Day = day then date::acc, None
        else match following with
             | Some f when date.Year = f.Year
                        && date.Month = f.Month
                        && date.Day < day -> f::acc, None
             | _ -> acc, Some date)
    |> fst

let expected = [ DateTime(2010, 2, 2)
                 DateTime(2010, 3, 2)
                 DateTime(2010, 4, 4) ]

let actual =
    [| DateTime(2010, 2, 1)
       DateTime(2010, 2, 2)
       DateTime(2010, 2, 5)
       DateTime(2010, 2, 6)
       DateTime(2010, 3, 1)
       DateTime(2010, 3, 2)
       DateTime(2010, 4, 1)
       DateTime(2010, 4, 4) |]
    |> filterDayOrFollowing 2

actual = expected |> printfn "actual = expected: %b"
```